# SQL Search function to order by appearance in columns

Tags: sql, search

I have an SQL search function built up as following:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Table
WHERE
    Question LIKE @SearchString
    OR Answer LIKE @SearchString
    OR Keywords LIKE @SearchString
```

And I want to order them by relevance, meaning the results where Keywords LIKE @SearchString on top, followed by Answer LIKE @SearchString and then Question LIKE @SearchString. But I can't seem to figure out how despite several googling efforts.

I found somewhere that

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(FAQ_FAQ.Keywords, @SearchString, 1) > 0 THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END ASC,
```

Might work, but apparently it doesn't.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Table
WHERE
    Keywords LIKE @SearchString
    OR Answer LIKE @SearchString
    OR Question LIKE @SearchString
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN Keywords LIKE @SearchString THEN 0
         WHEN Answer LIKE @SearchString THEN 1
         ELSE 2
    END
```

Comment: this did the trick! thx! tried something similar before, but the "LIKE" gave me errors for some reason

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the `UNION ALL` route:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Table 
WHERE 
    Question LIKE @SearchString 

union all

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Table 
WHERE 
    Answer LIKE @SearchString 

union all

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Table 
WHERE 
    Keywords LIKE @SearchString
```

You could even take it as far as this:

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT 
        *, 1 as OrderRank
    FROM 
        Table 
    WHERE 
        Question LIKE @SearchString 

    union all

    SELECT 
        *, 2 as OrderRank 
    FROM 
        Table 
    WHERE 
        Answer LIKE @SearchString 

    union all

    SELECT 
        *, 3 as OrderRank 
    FROM 
        Table 
    WHERE 
        Keywords LIKE @SearchString 
)a
order by OrderRank
```

Comment: for a union trick to work, you should add some pseudo-column like 1,2,3 and then wrap the entire thing into another select so you can order by the new numbers.

Comment: @Randy that's exactly what I did :)

Comment: The 2nd query is pretty good if you don't mind (or want!) duplicate (or triplicate) rows of the table to be shown when these rows match 2 or 3 of the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Somthing like this maybe?

```
select * from (
    select
      t.*,
      case when Question LIKE @SearchString then 1 
           when Answer   LIKE @SearchString then 2
           when Keywords LIKE @SearchString then 3
      end crit
     from table t
) where crit > 0
order by crit desc
```

Comment: Right, `desc` was missing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. There is another tiny detail: I see that you use lowercase for SQL keywords (except LIKE) — to my eyes, lowercase SQL looks much more readable than the [common uppercase convention](https://www.sqlstyle.guide/). Do you maybe have an alternative SQL design guide at hand?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the three things distinctly and union them together so get the results you are looking for.  There may be a better way but I am not aware of it.  Are you familiar with how to union?